# Shoud I prefer <nav><ul><li><a-or-other-tag> or <nav><a-or-other-tag>, from an accessibility standpoint?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, navbar, nav

Often, in books, tutorials, and some actual webpage, I see navigation bars marked up as `<li>`s elements in a `<ul>` element in a `<nav>` element, like this:

```css
.site-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.site-nav > li > a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li { padding: 1em; } /* just for better appearance here on SO */
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="site-nav">
    <li><a href="x">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="y">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="z">third</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

However, why shouldn't I prefer a solution like the following, where the `<nav>` contains directly all the contents of the `<li>`s from the example above?

```css
.site-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.site-nav > a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <a href="x">first</a>
  <a href="y">second</a>
  <a href="z">third</a>
</nav>
```

One advantage I see is the lower specificity needed to target the `<a>` links (or whatever I'd put in their place, e.g. `<button>`s), but I still know too little about HTML to understand the implications of one or the other solution, especially as far as accessibility is concerned.

Comment: Perhaps this topic will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544885/should-i-use-uls-and-lis-inside-my-navs

Comment: @IvanBeliakov, in fact this question of mine is a duplicated of that. I didn't find it though.

Comment: The linked answer is not related / relavent. This question is about removing the `<ul>` not about what role the container element should be (which is correct as a `<nav>` element), please reopen or find a better duplicate answer if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is straight forward, semantics and accessibility.

If I arrive at your second example without the `<ul>` with a screen reader then I have no idea how many links there are.

If I arrive at the first, correctly marked up example with a screen reader I will hear something similar to "navigation landmark, list of 3 items".

This lets me know that there are 3 links in the list so I can visualise where I am in the navigation as I move between them.

Answer (score 1):

HTML tags have (with some exceptions like `div` and `span`) semantic meaning. And you need to check what effects their presence or absence could have.

In the [spec.whatwg.org: 4.3.4 The nav element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-nav-element)

You have this example:

```
<nav>
 <h1>Navigation</h1>
 <p>You are on my home page. To the north lies <a href="/blog">my
 blog</a>, from whence the sounds of battle can be heard. To the east
 you can see a large mountain, upon which many <a
 href="/school">school papers</a> are littered.
 …
```

So there you have a full text in the `nav` element. For a blind person, the screen reader will read this text so that `You are on my home page. To the north lies <a href="/blog">my blog</a>` can be understood as `You are on my home page. To the north lies my blog.` With the information that `my blog` is a link pointing to the blog.

For your last example:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
  <a href="x">first</a>
  <a href="y">second</a>
  <a href="z">third</a>
</nav>
```

What do you think how should the screen read present the content of `nav` to the person, as the sentence `first second third` with the information that each word of this "sentence" is a link? This does not make much sense, right?

That's why you group the links using a `ul` or `ol` element. To give it the semantic meaning that `first second third` isn't a sentence but a list of items.

You probably could assume that a particular screen reader could be intelligent enough to determine that your second example does not contain a sentence. But then you rely on an optional behavior a screen reader might have introduced to get around the problem when sites don't introduce enough semantics.